# Can you say “a lot of dog” as a meaning of “much dog”?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, semantics, quantifiers

When you read the sentences below, is it possible to change the phrase "much dog" into "a lot of dog"?

He (a dog) needed grooming. I didn't think there was very much dog inside all that fur, but he had bright attentive eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That change of phrase is perfectly acceptable but more informal.

[**Much** and **a** **lot**, Cambridge.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers)